# How should I change my study habit of university math?

Tags: self-learning, advice, learning

I'm currently in my final year of a physics major. I have always been interested in math, and decided to take some courses in the math department. I have taken a semester of Mathematical analysis based on Apostol textbook, finishing the first 9 chapters. Recently, I also took a semester of abstract algebra based on Keith Nicholson's Introduction to Abstract algebra, covering the part of group theory and the chapter about p-groups and the Sylow theorems.

However,  I  didn't do very well on the tests on both these 2 courses. I'm not a guy that really like to attend lectures, since in my opinion this is somehow a passive and inefficient way to learn things. I instead try to prove every theorem on the text, and even if I get stuck, I would still spent hours to come up the proof on my own. After I'm confident with my proof, I looked up the text and compare with my own proof. As for the homework part, I did it in a similar way when reading the textbook's theory part, proving every exercises assigned without looking at any solution, and TA had marked high scores on my homework. After that, I did almost all the exercises on both books. Could anyone give me some advice on how to improve my study method on math? Thnks.

Comment: Sounds like what I did at University. Two things though. 1) You should probably attend the lectures. 2) You should probably spend a good amount of time doing exam preparation. That is, assuming you care about your exam results. But in general, what you're doing seems fine to me. But I've no doubt others will disagree.

Comment: For me, attending lectures to see a lecturer work through a problem, and talking to other people taking maths at the same time, were far far greater value than working through a textbook on my own.

Comment: To improve your grades, there's a great benefit of attending lectures in that you see which topics the professor emphasizes and you can focus on those topics when you study. You might have a deep understanding of some proofs that will not be covered on an exam, and yet be failing to master some other *easier* material that you didn't focus on. Try to guess what the professor thinks is important and focus on that. Also, if there is a very large amount of material and you are having trouble learning all of it, it can help to learn in a "big picture first" manner.

Answer (score 2):

As a former professor of both physics *and* mathematics, I may have some insight on this question.

My first recommendation is the obvious:  If you're not going to class and not doing well on exams, *then go to class*!!  I am extremely skeptical of anyone but towering mathematical geniuses (some of whom I know personally) to learn mathematics without the benefit of classes.

[One of my tricks to get students to come to class is that I say I will solve one problem in class that is *not* in the textbook (which I wrote!), that will be essentially verbatim on an exam.]

Your core problem seems to be that you think classes are "passive."  *Hah*!  Not at all!  Ask questions.  Anticipate steps in derivations.  *Think* during a lecture.

You're likely to spend more time thrashing around, frankly wasting time, as you seem to be doing by "deriving theorems on your own."  And you won't truly know what *is* and what *is not* important.  Not every theorem is equally important, or equally worth your time and effort.  As a student you simply and positively cannot know that.

Next, given that you have a background in physics, you might profit from applying the math to physics problems where you have background and insight.  I know I learned how to perform differentiation and integration in high-school mathematics, but I truly *understood* calculus when I applied it to physics, both Newtonian mechanics and electricity and magnetism.

Answer (score 0):

If You have said elementary - high school maths classes are passive, I would have agreed. Do not expect Your professor to teach everything, You should ask him what You want to know, discuss with him. The greatest value of university is the opportunity to meet many people who share the same interest with You (including Your professor), talk to them, ask for their ideas on stuffs, learn from them. In university, I always learn from people around me, even people who failed the class have some very interesting insights when i discussed with them.

Your approach to maths is great, do it before Your class then discuss it in class.